# Using mod_rewrite to 301 to SERVER_NAME

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have many ServerAlias'es in my Apache vhost and I want all domains that aren't the ServerName to be 301'ed to the ServerName.

This is not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !%{SERVER_NAME} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This does work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.some-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Can I do this without hard coding the domain name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables are only expanded on the left hand side of `RewriteCond`. But you can use backreferences like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%{SERVER_NAME} !^([^/]+)/\1$
```

Answer (score 0):

the domain name is part of the CondPattern of RewriteCond.

the CondPattern is rendered on Startup of the httpd, so it can not contain any dynamic server variables ..

so this will not work ..