# Dynamic Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, vhosts

How can I make this dynamic? So that it is usable for every 'user' and website. (For example

```
<VirtualHost server-ip:80>
  ServerName user.website.nl
  DocumentRoot /var/wwww/user/website.nl
  ...
```

So for example kevin.website.nl will display the content from /var/www/kevin/website.nl. And when /var/www/kevin/test.com/ exists, then when I visit kevin.test.com it will display the content in that directory. Or if user 'thomas' exists and /var/www/thomas/abc.com/ exists and we visit thomas.abc.com, it will load from that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably using [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

You can also do this with the environment variables of mod_rewrite I believe. You'll need to use a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071883/using-mod-rewrite-to-301-to-server-name) to do this though.

Comment: Thanks! Now I do this:

    # Enable mod_vhost_alias
    # a2enmod vhost_alias
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2.-2/%3+

But when I visit kevin.website.com, it displays 'Not found' (website.com is bound to the server).